# Two installations of Oracle APEX listeners

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

Is it possible to have 2 installations of APEX listeners?

Currently I have the EPG (Embedded PL/SQL Gateway) listener being used as a listener for one PDB, say PDB-A.

Simulataneously, I want to utilize the ORDS (Oracle REST Data Services) listener for a different PDB, say PDB-B?

Current is a multitenant APEX setup with the original in the CDB-root and seeded with a PDB-SEED.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
The main difference is the URLs will be /ords/pdb-a and /ords/pdb-b.

The catch is if the APEXes are different versions there will have to be a /i-pdba and /i/pdb-b setup.

To add the 2nd db

```
java -jar ords.war setup --database pdb-b
```

then to map the url

```
java -jar ords.war map-url --type base-path /pdb-b pdb--b
```